# HDD connected to mac with thunderbolt 3 to USB 3 adaptor is not recognized

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, usb, thunderbolt

I have a MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2017, Four Thunderbolt 3 Ports) running High Sierra. I usually leave my HDD on with the adaptor, then plug the adapter into the same port every time I need to use it. However, usually the HDD will not show up in Finder, `diskutil list`, or `lsusb`. Replugging does not work. Connecting it to another port will work, as well as plugging in another device (in my case, Belkin USB C to LAN adaptor) to the port not working before reconnecting the HDD to the same port. Is there any way I can troubleshoot what is happening? This problem is really annoying because I need to unplug the Belkin adaptor to make the HDD connect, and I lose internet for a period of time which means I need to reconnect network mounts and open YouTube tabs.

I've tried to connect the HDD through another adaptor, but that didn't work. I've also tried to connect the HDD to another port, but after some time the same behavior appeared. It seems like it is a general issue with thunderbolt 3, not specific ports or adaptors.

Comment: So: Plugging the HDD into one TB port doesn't work, unless you plug in something else first? Other ports don't behave in this way? My first thought is that it's a problem with the port. Can you not just change which devices go into each port, so that the HDD uses a different port?

Comment: If it's not the port that's the problem, then replace the adaptor. You should be able to use a cheap USB-C to USB A cable (if that's what you need).

Comment: It seems like it is related to the implementation of thunderbolt 3 on mbp. I've heard of news of weird things that happen with thunderbolt 3, but I haven't done research.